# How to find Excel column Index By its value using Apache poi

Tags: apache, apache-poi

Currently i am using apache poi to read the data from Excel file.

I have situvation to get the columnIndex by Value.

I mean , Excel file contains 10000 rows.

Second column contains list of emp names , i want to find the column index by 
value.

Means:Emp name "Ra" in 10th Column , I should get column index when i pass value. I need solution without using foreach or iterator.

Comment: Why can't you just do a foreach / iterator loop? That's the normal way....

Comment: Using foreach i am able to get the data . i just trying alternative to improve the performance .

Comment: Did you profile it? How do you know it has poor performance?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Search {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String path = "src/test.xlsx";
        String param = "Ra";
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(path); 
                XSSFWorkbook w = new XSSFWorkbook(in)) {

            List<Integer> lstStringIndex = new ArrayList<>();
            SharedStringsTable stringsTable = w.getSharedStringSource();
            for (int i = 0; i < stringsTable.getCount(); i++) {
                if (stringsTable.getEntryAt(i).getT().contains(param)) {
                    lstStringIndex.add(i);
                }
            }

            XSSFSheet s = w.getSheetAt(0);
            String xml = s.getCTWorksheet().xmlText();
            for (Integer i : lstStringIndex) {
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=<main:c r=\")[A-Z0-9]+(?=\" t=\"s\"><main:v>" + i + "</main:v>)");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(xml);
                if(m.find()) {
                    System.out.println(m.group());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will print out the adress of any cell that contain "Ra".
I'm using apache poi 3.14 btw.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but i dont want to use for/foreach. Just checking is there any way to get the cell number by Value without iteration.